# Lucene can't iterate over TokenStream multiple times

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to iterate over a TokenStream multiple times in my custom Filter.

```
   @Override
   public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
      if (first) {
         while (input.incrementToken()) {
            System.out.println(
                  "[" + input.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString() +
                        ", " + offsetAttribute.startOffset() +
                        ", " + offsetAttribute.endOffset() +
                        "," + positionIncrementAttribute.getPositionIncrement() +
                        "] "
            );
         }
         first = false;
         super.reset();
         return true;
      }
      if (!this.input.incrementToken()) {
         return false;
      }
      this.charTermAttribute.setEmpty().append(input.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString());
      this.positionIncrementAttribute.setPositionIncrement(1);
      return true;
   }
```

My need is to have all the tokens in a list (I'm just displaying them for the moment) and then, modify my Tokens based on some logic which is based on this list.

This is the output:

```
[125, 0, 3,1] 
[RUE, 5, 8,1] 
[DE, 9, 11,1] 
[LA, 12, 14,1] 
[REPUBLIQUE, 15, 25,1] 
[souffre, 27, 34,1] 
[de, 35, 37,1] 
[LA, 38, 40,1] 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.
```

Any idea please ?

Lucene 4.7.2

Comment: you need to implement reset method, did you do it?

Comment: @Mysterion: I moved the while loop in the reset method but nothing. What do you suggest as implementation in the reset method ? thnx

Comment: you have like 2 similar questions and i do not get what you want to do and what is your real problem

Comment: in this case, i do not get why you calling super.reset() in the incrementToken method. for sure you do not need to do it

Comment: @Mysterion: What I want to do is have the entire tokens and then while consuming the stream, make some changes to the current Token based on some logic on the saved token in the ArrayList.
Now that I iterate over the stream in the reset, the incrementToken method returns directly false because the stream is already consumed. I really don't see how :s